# How to paint on SWT shell borders on Windows?

Tags: java, windows, swt, desktop

I know this is not possible with just SWT, but tricks using JNA or similar are welcome.

Similar to applications like chrome I don't want the title bar of my shell be painted by windows but by myself, so I can e.g. place tab handles there. I also wonder how I could reliable mimik the typical Windows buttons like - [] X, and provide the Windows specific menus here.

Any ideas?